# Calling a function without clicking anything

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to call a function without any button or click event. I'm doing a table within a table using javascript function. Here's my code so far:

```
<html>
<head> <title> Hello </title> </head>
<body>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' /> <script> add(); </script> <div id='myDiv'> </div> </td>
    </tr>

<script>
$ctra = 1;
$ctr1a = 1;  
function add() { 
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
    numi.value = num;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1>"+
                        "<tr>"+
                        "<td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' /> <script> add(); </script> <div id=('" + divIdName + "')> </div> </td>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                        "</table>";
    if($ctra<100){
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
        $ctra++;
    }
}
</script>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, it displays

```
"+ ""+ "
Hello!
"; if($ctra<100){ ni.appendChild(newdiv); $ctra++; } }
```

in the browser. What could the problem be? Thank you in advance!
**EDIT**

```
function add() { 
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
    numi.value = num;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value=0 id='theValue' /><div id='" + divIdName + "'></td></tr></table>";
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    for(var i=1;i<100;i++) {
        var ni = document.getElementById(divIdName);
        var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
        var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
        numi.value = num;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
        newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='" + i + "' id='theValue' /><div id='" + divIdName + "'></td></tr></table>";
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: your script doesn't seem to be right place. write it in head section and then call your funcation

Comment: @vahit. if you have got your solution then mark that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head> <title> Hello </title> </head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $ctra = 1;
    $ctr1a = 1;
    function add() { 
    alert('s')
    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
    var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
    numi.value = num;
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' /></tr></table>";
    if($ctra<100){
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);
        $ctra++;
    }
}

</script>

<body onload="add()">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' />

        <div id='myDiv'> </div> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it works for you..:)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! Another question, is there a way I can call like `<body onload="add()">` for 100 times? I know it will only call `add()` once even if I copy-paste it forever. I'm trying to create a table within a table 100x. It seems that the `if` statement inside the function is not working.

Comment: ya. You if want so then change your if condition by For loop. There is no need of if condition. you can iterate that code using loop. try this
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{ //do your work }

Comment: Marked. :) I see.. However, it just creates 100 different tables inside the main table. It has to generate a table within a table. I'm confused, does every iteration change the values of the variables?

Comment: Thanks :), iteration changes the value of i. What you code is doing, it appends a table to MainDiv(ni.append(newdiv) in every iteration. If you want to add table in table the you need to append newdiv to recently added div

Comment: I thought the `divIdName` in the line `newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' /><div id='" + divIdName + "'></td></tr></table>";` already does that. Has `theValue` something to do with that? Is there a way I can change their values? :)

Comment: function add() {
        var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        var numi = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            alert(i);
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            var divIdName = 'my' + i + 'Div';
            newdiv.setAttribute('id', divIdName);
            newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1><tr><td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' /></tr></table>";

            ni.appendChild(newdiv);
            ni = document.getElementById('my' + i + 'Div');
            alert(ni.getAttribute('Id'));
        }
    }
replace it

Comment: Thanks sir but it's still the same. It doesn't generate a table within a table. I tried to modify my code also. Pls see edit. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your JS results in nested  blocks, this isn't allowed in html.  The function add() in your blocks is not defined, because when the browser encounters it, it hasn't seen your definition of add() yet.  Your table contains a script that contains another table which contains yet another script.  It's very confusing :P

OK, if i understand correctly: you have a single table.  You'd like to have JS put another table inside. The thing you want to put inside is, in this example, a copy of the table.  You want to end up with a table inside a table and you want to achieve it programatically.

First separate your concerns: scripts and html:
If you put your add() after the definition and you put your script after the body then the browser will encounter it and run it.  HTH:

```
<html>
<head> <title> Hello </title> </head>
<body>
    <table id="t1" border=1>
        <tr>
            <td> Hello! <input type='hidden' value='0' id='theValue' />
                <div id='myDiv'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
    function add_table() {
        var table1 = document.getElementById("t1"),
            table2 = table1.cloneNode(true),
            mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"),
            mydiv2;

        table2.setAttribute('id', 't2');
        mydiv2 = table2.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        mydiv2.setAttribute('id', 'myDiv2');
        mydiv.appendChild(table2);
    }
    // call the function
    add_table();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup sir, that's what I'm trying to do. :) Your code make one table within a table. Thanks! I'd like to do that 100x. So I tried `table3.setAttribute('id', 't3');
        mydiv3 = table3.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
        mydiv3.setAttribute('id', 'myDiv3');
        mydiv2.appendChild(table3);` to add another table, making the previous block a pattern. But it does not work. What could be done to address this problem?

Comment: Yikes! One hundred times!  That may not be possible.  Have a play with this: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/electrophoto/jLBJ4/

Answer (score 0):

You have `</script>` inside the code. Browser interprets that as an end of javascript and breaks back to HTML. To fix this, you can divide this string into for example `</sc'+'ript>`. That will fix this issue, but probably you'll still have to work a bit on the script, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch between differents quotes, and remove braces for the id, like this :

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<table border=1>"
    +"<tr>"
    +'<td> Hello! <input type="hidden" value="0" id="theValue" /> '
    +'<script> add(); </script> <div id="' + divIdName + '"> </div> </td>'
    +"</tr>"
    +"</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you cant access the function without any evnt in the dom..You have to call the function on any event of the elemnt.

Answer (score 0):

1. move the script outside the table-element to the head or to the end of the body.
2. first add the div, then call the script. you might want to call your `add()` in `<body onload='add'>`
3. remove the braces here to create valid html: `<div id=('" + divIdName + "')>`